# cant check if a string exists in a dictionary [python]

Tags: python, string, dictionary, search

I have a dictionary in python and it includes 200 keys and each key has long strings and several lines as a value

EXAMPLE OF DICTIONARY

```
var_holder = {
    "text0": 'Montgomery\n\nBirmingham Juneau. Phoenix\n\nSacramento ,\nChicago\n\nSpringfield: Atlanta\n\x0c'
}
```

WHAT I NEED
to check if these values contain a certain word

WHAT I DID

```
value = 'Phoenix'
if any([True for k,v in var_holder.items() if v == value]):
    print(f"Yes, Value: '{value}' exists in dictionary")
else:
    print(f"No, Value: '{value}' does not exists in dictionary")
```

OUTPUT
No, Value: 'Phoenix' does not exists in dictionary

EXPECTED OUTPUT
Yes, Value: 'Phoenix' does exists in dictionary

can someone please correct my code ?
or suggest another way of doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I recommend you to do:

```py
var_holder = {
    "text0": 'Montgomery\n\nBirmingham Juneau. Phoenix\n\nSacramento ,\nChicago\n\nSpringfield: Atlanta\n\x0c'
}

value = 'Phoenix'
gen = (v for v in var_holder.values() if value in v)

if gen:
    print(f"Yes, Value: '{value}' exists in dictionary")
else:
    print(f"No, Value: '{value}' does not exists in dictionary")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `in` for finding value in the string instead of `==` comparison.

```
var_holder = {
    "text0": 'Montgomery\n\nBirmingham Juneau. Phoenix\n\nSacramento ,\nChicago\n\nSpringfield: Atlanta\n\x0c'
}

value = 'Phoenix'
if any(value in v for v in var_holder.values()):
    print(f"Yes, Value: '{value}' exists in dictionary")
else:
    print(f"No, Value: '{value}' does not exists in dictionary")
```

Comment: `any(value in v for v in var_holder.values())` would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
var_holder = {
    "text0": 'Montgomery\n\nBirmingham Juneau. Phoenix\n\nSacramento ,\nChicago\n\nSpringfield: Atlanta\n\x0c'
    }

value = 'Phoenix'
if any(value in x for x in var_holder.values()):
    print(f"Yes, Value: '{value}' exists in dictionary")
else:
    print(f"No, Value: '{value}' does not exists in dictionary")
```